# Serializer field 'source' argument does not work when validating

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Why does 'source' not work when trying to validate data?

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Test(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.CharField(source='myField')
    
test_data = {'myField': 'test1', 'myOtherField': 'test2'}

Test(test_data).data
```

The output: {'my_field': 'test1'}.

```
Test(test_data).is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

The output: AssertionError: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

```
Test(data=test_data).is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

The output: ValidationError: {'my_field': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}

Comment: `source` defines the name of the attribute in the object, not the key in JSON

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I'm curious, where in the docs does it say that?

Comment: @rhoward [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) it is, check this out. says `The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field.`

Comment: @Dad I meant where in the docs does it say that we're talking about the attributes of models as opposed to the attributes of JSON data.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you should set myField instead of serializer field and set source to my_field (The name you want your field to have).

I gave you an example here:

In serializers.py:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    TestField = serializers.CharField(source="test_field")
```

In views.py:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView, Response
from .serializers import TestSerializer

class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        test_data = {"TestField": "This is a test value"}
        
        serializer = TestSerializer(data=test_data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        print(serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(serializer.validated_data)
```

The output of this serializer is:

```bash
>>> OrderedDict([('test_field', 'This is a test value')])
```

More about source attributes: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: Did you mean to include a link to another site at the end?